# A template system in CodeIgniter that allows me to pass data from a model in to the header automatically?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been looking at CodeIgniter template systems and all so far, it allows you to change content within the header or footer file, but I am looking for a way to load data in to the header file from a model automatically (dependent on the template).

For example, in my header, it displays the users username and inbox. I need to load the users unread messages from a model and the users username. This is dependent on the template though - I only want to load that information if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing data from model to a view is not a good practice.

You should pass data first to the controller and only then to your view.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html

As you can see on this application flow chart - there is no straight line between model and view.

If you are interested in displaying model data in your "layout" - use hooks!

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Define a "pre_controller" hook, get CI instance, load model, retrive data and display it in your layout.

Enable hooks

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Define a hook like:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'MyClass',
                                'function' => 'Myfunction',
                                'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => array('beer', 'wine', 'snacks')
                                );
```

E.g.

Hook

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Gamescount
{
        private $model_name = '';

        public function __construct() 
        {
                $this->CI =& get_instance();
                $this->model_name = 'Games_model';
                $this->CI->load->database();
                $this->CI->load->model($this->model_name);
                $this->CI->load->helper('url');
        }

        public function count_games()
        {
                $all_games = $this->CI->Games_model->getAllGames();
                $this->CI->gamescount = count($all_games);
        }
}

?>
```

In your layout you can get gamescount value like

```
<?php echo $this->gamescount; ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps I was misunderstood? I don't want to load the data directly into the view from the model, I was more looking at some sort of template library that allows me to load data from a model to be displayed. So the template library for example acts as an intermediary between the model and header view.

Comment: You need to display your data in a "layout"? Use hooks...see edited post for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the code to retrieve the data in a controller and then load it through AJAX and display in header. That is a feasible solution without breaking the Codeigniter practice.

Comment: I guess for the amount on unread items in the inbox yes as it would have to update through ajax anyway but for the username, I might just store in a session when the user signs in.

Comment: Please set the username to the session when user login in the controller and after that can be used in view without passing it. So no need to load data from model. If you expect some tools to generate Codeigniter CRUD functions then you might check www.thephpcode.com

Answer (score -1):

As Parker mentioned, it is not a good idea to call a model from view. But if you still want to do it, you can do it.

Get the Codeigniter instance as follows

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

Using Codeigniter instance,You can call the model.